# In Unity, how can I check if an input was made x seconds/frames ago?

Tags: unity, input, frame-buffer

I'm using the [Rewired](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21676) input plugin, and it comes with an [input buffer](http://guavaman.com/projects/rewired/docs/RewiredEditor.html#InputBehaviors). I enabled the buffer for my directional keys and airdash button so that the player doesn't have to hit both keys on the same frame in order to dash.

However, this means that if you press both keys and hold them down for more than a frame, the airdash code gets run again. I tried to stop this by comparing `Time.time` at the beginning of `Update()` to `Time.time` at the beginning of the coroutine, but this seems inconsistent and it doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

How would you check for the player's input time and compare it to the time since some previous input?

Here's a sample of the dash code within `FixedUpdate()`

```
        //Dash

        if (grounded)
        {
            dashCount = 0;
            dashTime = 0;
        }

        if (dashCount < 2)
        {
            //print(currentTime - dashTime);
            if (currentTime - dashTime < 0.1 || dashCount == 0)
            {
                //Double Tap Dash
                if (player.GetButtonDoublePressDown("Left"))
                {
                    StartCoroutine(Dash("left"));
                }

                //Button Dash
                if (player.GetButtonDown("Dash") && player.GetButtonDown("Left"))
                {
                    StartCoroutine(Dash("left"));
                }
            }

        }

        print(dashCount);
```

and here's a sample of the coroutine:

```
    //Dash
    IEnumerator Dash(string axis) {

        dashCount++;

        dashTime = Time.time;

        if (axis == "left")
        {
            if (inDash == true)
            {
                anim.SetBool("dashUp", false);
                anim.SetBool("dashDown", false);
                anim.SetBool("Hover", false);
            }
            canControl = false;
            inDash = true;
            anim.SetBool("dashHorizontal", true);
            anim.SetBool("inDash", true);
            rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody2D.velocity.x, 0);
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(-dashForceHorizontal, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rigidbody2D.velocity, maxVelocity);
            rigidbody2D.gravityScale = 0;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);


            rigidbody2D.gravityScale = 2;
            rigidbody2D.drag = 25f;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);


            if (grounded == true)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            }

            rigidbody2D.drag = 0f;
            canControl = true;
            anim.SetBool("dashHorizontal", false);
            anim.SetBool("inDash", false);

            inDash = false;

            yield break;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume we have button `A` and button `B` and you want to be able to press both of them but not in the same frame.

The general way of accomplishing this is the following:

`on button A key press
    if button B is currently pressed
        execute action
end`

`on button B key press
    if button A is currently pressed
        execute action
end`

combining the two logics you can get

`on button A or button B key press
    if both button A and button B are currently pressed
        execute action
end`

Now, if you want to make sure the users can press the two buttons in different frames but not more than 2 seconds apart we can slightly alter the above code as follow:

`on button A or button B key press
    if we can handle the action
        execute action
    else
        mark that we can handle the action and
        //eventually additional logic, if required
        start a couroutine that will mark disable the action handling in 2 seconds
    end`

This is a generic way that can be used to solve your issue. You will of course need to customize it for your own problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get the gist of what you're saying and I see how it would work for a variable, but I still can't figure out how to apply this to time. How can the engine compare the time between two inputs? Should I just use `Time.time` like I initially tried?

Comment: I don't see why you need to compare time in this specific problem. You have to look for "key down" events. That means when the user pressed the button not while it is pressed or released. In Unity you achieve this with [GetKeyDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html). This way your code will no longer start running multiple times but only when both conditions are satisfied (key down and both key pressed at that time).